# How to force ffmpeg to use all the images in a directory?

Tags: ffmpeg, png, mp4, movie

I have a directory of images, (*.png)s, and I am trying to make a movie out of them using ffmpeg.

The images are named in multiple of 50, so I have: `images_0000.png`, then, `images_0050.png`, then `images_0100.png`, then `images_0150.png`, etc, all the way to `images_4950.png`, and so I have 100 images in total.

I use the following command to make my movie:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 movie.mp4
```

This works fine to make the movie, however when I play it, does not look like *every* image is being used. That is, if I step through frame by frame, I see that some images are not being displayed, and it looks like they were skipped. (I know because every image has it's name written on it).

So, how do I force ffmpeg to use every image in the directory, such that every step forward in the movie, will show the corresponding image?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the complete screen dump of the command:

[image]

Comment: Show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I just edited with the total screen grab.

Comment: Thanks, but why not just copy and paste the text instead of making an image of text? Images are not searchable, take more space, and you can't copy any text from images.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I tried to paste the text in, but it kept mucking up the formatting.

Comment: 2.7.2 is old. [Get a recent version](http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) (the snapshot, not the release). Then use `-framerate` input option instead of `-r` for the image file demuxer. Add the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` output option if you want the output to play in QuickTime (but QT may not like certain low frame rates...but I did not test).

Answer (score 1):

Comment from llogan said it all.

use `-framerate` and not `-r` in your pipeline. Something like:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 movie.mp4
```

The `-r` acts like a filter and will filter out from your input to match the targeted framerate.